# Postgres Calculate Difference Using Window Functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, window-functions

I apologize in advance if the question is too basic. Window functions are fun and challenging at the same time!

I have two Postgres tables such as below called client and order.

```
id | name
------------
41 | james
29 | melinda
36 | henry
...

id | date | volume | client_id
------------------------------
328 | 2018-01-03 | 16 | 41
411 | 2018-01-29 | 39 | 29
129 | 2018-01-13 | 73 | 29
542 | 2018-01-22 | 62 | 36
301 | 2018-01-17 | 38 | 41
784 | 2018-01-08 | 84 | 29
299 | 2018-01-10 | 54 | 36
300 | 2018-01-10 | 18 | 36
178 | 2018-01-30 | 37 | 36
...
```

a) How can I write a query to find the largest difference in order volume for each client? For example, `client_id = 36` should show `(54 + 18) - 37 = -35`. This is because orders placed on the same day by the same client should count as one order.

b) How can I find the difference in volume between the two most recent orders for each client? For example, `client_id = 29` should show `39 - 73 = -34`

Comment: I dont know if T-SQL query will help you?? I can tell a query to get your result

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm not very familiar with T-SQL, but I'd prefer to approach this with postgres syntax and window functions. Do you think you can help me out?

Comment: I think sql query may help. ok tell the exact formula you want to write a query for that. I mean instead of (54+..... tell a formula like (MaxV - MinV ....

Comment: For each unique client_id: Max(total volume for each day) - Min(total volume for each day), does that help?

Comment: If my answer helped you so it woud be easy to query the part B.

Answer (score 5):

Well here is a T-SQL.
For this formula as you said ---> Max(total volume each day) - Min(total volume each day)
May help you.

```
SELECT (X.Max(SumV)-X.Min(SumV))
From (
     SELECT Client_Id,Date,SUM(Volume) AS SumV
     FROM Orders
     GROUP BY Client_id,Date
     ) X

Group by X.Client_Id
```